# This ite can't be reached (PHP mailer)

Tags: php, html, forms, email, phpmailer

When I try to submit the completed form it must redirect me to a success page to indicate that the email has been sent successfully. But unfortunately, this appears and the email doesn't come
[image site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPi8L.jpg)

This is the code

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
 
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';
 
// Instantiation and passing [ICODE]true[/ICODE] enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
 
try {

    function get_ip() {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
          return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) { 
         return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else {
         return (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '');
        
          }
        }
    //Server settings
    $ip=get_ip();
    $query=@unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isMail();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '//';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '///';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, [ICODE]ssl[/ICODE] also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $ips=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $landline = $_POST['landline'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $people = $_POST['people'];
    $lunch = $_POST['lunch'];
    $enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];
    $questions = $_POST['questions'];
    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress('bookings@rios.com.au', 'Rios bookings');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addAddress($email, $name);     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('bookings@rios.com.au', 'Information from customer');
    // $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    // $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
 
    // // Attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/home/cpanelusername/attachment.txt');         // Add attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/home/cpanelusername/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
 
    // Content
    // $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Rio E-mail from Website / Contact Us Form';
$mail->Body = "
New Message from Rio Contact Form

Name: {$name}

Email: {$email}

Mobile: {$mobile}

Landline: {$landline}

Date: {$date}

People: {$people}

Lunch or Dinner: {$lunch}

Enquiry or booking: {$enquiry}

Questions: {$questions}
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
{$ips} {$query['city']} {$query['regionName']} {$query['zip']} {$query['timezone']}
";
    header('location:success.html');
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

This is how I have organized the files
[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmxMf.jpg)

....................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good pattern:

```
header('location:success.html');
$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
```

You don't know that sending has succeeded until *after* calling `send()`, and any content you output after setting the header will either be lost (because it redirects away before it can be seen), or it will prevent the redirect from happening (because content is already sent). This should be enough, in this order:

```
$mail->send();
header('location:success.html');
exit; //Do nothing else after issuing the redirect
```

Strictly speaking, redirects should use absolute URLs, so perhaps add that into the destination address.

You're also doing this:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
...
$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
```

That's forgery and will probably end up getting your message blocked, bounced, or spam filtered. Do this instead:

```
$mail->setFrom('bookings@rios.com.au', $name);
$mail->addAddress('bookings@rios.com.au', 'Rios bookings');
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
```

This way the message is sent from you, to you, but replies will go to the submitter's address.

One other tip — learn how to use composer.